# How do I stop audio from playing?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

So I have 5 view controllers with multiple buttons on each one.

I also have a scroll view so you can slide/scroll in between them.

My Issue is that when I press a button on V1 a sound will play and if I slide over to V2 and press a button both sounds play on top of each other if the sound didn't finish on the first view (vice versa between any view).

I am using AVAudioPlayer

How can I prevent this from happening?

So I created objects such as :

```
let audioObject1 = AllViewsModel(title: "Watering Plants", sound: createPlayerAndFilePath("ILoveit")!)
```

I tagged each button like so:

```
 @IBAction func playPauseButtons(sender: UIButton) {

    switch sender.tag {


    case 10:

        stopAllSounds()
        startTimeAndPlayAudio(audioObject1.sound!)
        buttonSpringLikeAnimation(allButtonsConnectedToThisOutlet[0])
        print("1") }
```

The top function being called is all my audio object  :

```
func stopAllSounds() {

    audioObject1.sound?.stop()
    audioObject2.sound?.stop()
    audioObject3.sound?.stop()
    audioObject4.sound?.stop()
    audioObject5.sound?.stop()
    audioObject6.sound?.stop()
    audioObject7.sound?.stop()
    audioObject8.sound?.stop()
    audioObject9.sound?.stop()




}
```

Start and play function is me creating an AVAudioPlayes instance and locations the mp3:

```
func createPlayerAndFilePath(nameOfMediaFile: String) -> AVAudioPlayer? {

    do {

        let audioFile = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(nameOfMediaFile, ofType: "mp3")!), fileTypeHint: "AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3")

        return audioFile


    } catch {

        print("Audio file error")

    }

    return nil
}
```

I did this for 5 view controllers. I can stop the audio from overlapping in each view but if I press a button on a different one and say the first view is still playing is where I have an issue.

Comment: Use the same audio player, or tell the first audio player to stop.

Comment: @matt How would you go about doing that? I could prevent audio from playing over one another if its in the same View but now if I love to the second one or whatnot. Thanks

Comment: Surely V2 must know how to get a reference to V1, and thus it can get a reference to V1's audio player, and thus it can tell it to stop. If not, make it so. Or, as I said before, put the audio player at a higher level so that everyone can see it. It's your program; design it so that it does what you want.

Comment: @ matt well I am really new to this but the way I did this was to connect every button in say V1 to the same action and tag each button. In each case i stop the audio for all buttons then pay that designated sound. I did this for each view so now I am confused on what to do next to solve my issue. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Post some actual code into an edit so we can have a closer look, please.

Comment: @ caseynolan just added code to the edit. Thanks!

Comment: @ matt added some code to the edit

Comment: "I did this for 5 view controllers" But I'm saying: don't. Do it for _one_ object, for example it might be your app delegate. That way, you have _one_ centrally located audio player, all classes can see it and configure it, and (most important) when you create a new one you can stop and release the old one.

Comment: @matt has given you a solid solution, use one player that everyone can see. If you don't want to do that with AVAudioPlayer then you can use AVQueuePlayer, which will automatically stop playing the previous sound when another is loaded up and told to begin